# How come when I subdivide an edge, it only continues to subdivide one side?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm trying to create more vertices in an edge so I subdivide it, but for some reason, after I subdivide it once, it decides to only select one half of the subdivide. This messes with my faces when I then try to move them to shape them into what I'm modeling.

Before subdivide: [image]

After first subdivide: [image]

After second subdivide:[image]

What it's supposed to look like: [image]

It creating a weird face under on my model:[image]

Comment: best practice is to avoid ngons while modeling. having ngons would cause such problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the face on the right is already subdivided, and so is the edge between them. You should have subdivide them both at the same time.
[image]

You could fix this by selecting all the vertical edges between the faces and rip them (shortcut v). Then remove excess verts (select them and `x` -> `Dissolve Vertices`) on the face you're trying to subdivide. Subdivide the face. The verts on the right should allign. Now you have duplicated vertices in that region. Remove them by selecting all vers in the region (you'll probably have to turn on X-ray (`alt+Z`) to reach the duplicates) using `Merge by Distance`.